# Как в python Ubuntu20 управлять внешними программами?

Tags: python, linux, файлы

Пару недель как занимаюсь Python, поэтому если возможно, приводите примеры.
Есть сервер - Ubuntu20, на нем крутится некоторый софт. Входную папку читает отдельный скрипт, примерно раз в сек. Каким образом мне управлять - неоднократно запускать и останавливать этот скрипт ? Отдельно получается запуск файла:

```
def startproccess():
    path ="путь к программе"
    os.system(path to file)
```

Могу остановить с другого окна (использую Tmux)

```
def stopproccess():     
    name = "имя_процесса"
    for line in os.popen("ps ax | grep " + name + " | grep -v grep"):
        fields = line.split()
        pid = fields[0]
        os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

а вот такое не прокатывает:

```
startproccess()
time.sleep(10)
stopproccess()
```

На экран идет вывод информации из запущенной программы, ошибок не видно, не знаю в чем причина. Запуск производится от имени root.

Comment: `os.system` запускает процесс и ждет его завершения. Чтобы не ждать завершения и иметь возможность управлять процессом, используйте [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: В начале поста попросил примеры, трудно пока дается чтение доков. В результате копипаста чужих примеров попробовал subprocess.Popen(['sh',path]), тогда заводятся 2 процесса (фильтр по имени), первый "sh /home/user/***" и от него дочерний - "программа" где графически показано что она дочерняя по отношению к sh. В этом случае не срабатывает скрипт удаления процесса. Если запускать вручную то будет только один процесс - сама "программа", и тогда удаление процесса проходит успешно. Пробовал так: subprocess.Popen([path]), ошибка [Errno 8] Exec format error:

Comment: "[Errno 8] Exec format error:" - нужно смотреть что у вас в path записано.

Comment: вопрос решен по-другому, останавливаю ipmymon , подсовываю файлы и снова запускаю.